# after setting my array it display another content?

Tags: nsarray

i declared an array called "finalArray" inside a viewController and in the function ViewDidLoad i declared another array called "arr" that holds string variables from a text file.. after that I assigned the following within ViewDidLoad:

```
 NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    //to read from the file
     NSArray *arr = [fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
     self.finalArray = arr;
     [arr release];
```

the problem is that when i call this finalArray inside an action of button it display another content not my array?? i dont know what to do?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arr should not be released, because the method componentsSeparatedByString: returns an autoreleased NSArray. May be that the cause of your problem?

Comment: loooool thank you verrrry much yeah you were right,, I spent two nights trying to figure out what's the problem,,, thanks a million :)